# Asp.net: How to link a SiteMapPath to a SiteMapProvider

Tags: asp.net

I have a cutsom SiteMapProvider and i'm trying to connect it to my SiteMapPath control.

I already have a SiteMapDataSource as this :

```
<asp:SiteMapDataSource ID="SMDS1" runat="server" SiteMapProvider="SiteMapProvider" />
```

and a TreeView that is working

```
<asp:TreeView ID="tvwMenu" runat="server" DataSourceID="SMDS1"></asp:TreeView>
```

trying to add a SiteMapProvider to my SiteMapPath doesn't seem to be working
(edit: when i'm saying "not working", i mean not showing anything at all. I know it loads cause the load event is fired, but there is no items being created)

```
<asp:SiteMapPath ID="breadcrumb" runat="server" SiteMapProvider="SiteMapProvider" >
```

So how am I suppose to get my SiteMapPath to work?

Comment: You haven't set `DataSourceID` on your `SiteMapPath`.

Comment: But there is no such thing as a DataSourceId in a SiteMapPath

Comment: Yup, you're right. Its been a while. I think it uses the default SiteMapProvider defined in web.config. You can use an alternate provider with the [SiteMapProvider](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.sitemappath.sitemapprovider.aspx) property.

Comment: Well, as I said, the SiteMapProviderProperty doesn't work either.

Comment: So, if I understand correctly, the SiteMapPath will only be displayed on the page if the current url is known by the SiteMapProvider, right?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem solved !

The fact is that the TreeView doesn't need to know "where" he is (i.e. What page is being visited by the browser) while the SiteMapPath does need to know. So, to actually know this, the SiteMapPath will look at the URL to know "where" he is. The problem was that i was on a page named "siteNaviagionTester" which is nowhere near the Site map. So when i tried it on "index.aspx?page=pageName", it started workning just fine.

Hope this will help anyone else facing the same issue.